# Crop different portions of image from 4D array for data augmentation

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, multidimensional-array, computer-vision

I have the following batched RGB image array (4D array):

```
In [55]: img_arr = np.random.randint(0, 255, (10000, 32, 32, 3))
```

Now, I want to crop only certain dimensions, say (`12x12`), from the top left corner across all `3` channels, and preferably along the batch dimension (i.e. `axis 0`) as well, all in one go. My idea was to produce a grid and just slice it. So, I have constructed this grid:

```
In [56]: grid = np.c_[np.arange(12)]+ np.r_[np.arange(12)]

In [57]: grid.shape
Out[57]: (12, 12)
```

But, when I slice the array, I get something which is unexpected:

```
In [58]: img_arr[:, grid, :].shape
Out[58]: (10000, 12, 12, 32, 3)
```

I expected and need the result to be of shape `(10000, 12, 12, 3)` but I don't know where the `32` is coming from.

This is just an example. Ideally, I want to do this cropping at 10 different positions on the image viz. top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right etc.,

But, by first doing top-left cropping, the rest should be intuitive.

Additionally, as you can see I need to store more than 100K images along the batch dimension in a single 4D array, so it'd be very nice to have a *view* when doing such random  croppings, since it will be memory efficient.

Comment: How do you plan to introduce the 10 positions mathematically? Maybe `(x,y)` of the start (top-left corner pt) of each patch?

Comment: @Divakar with each original image crop portions at: `top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right, center crop`; Then, flip the image horizontally and again crop at: `top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right, and center crop`. Data augmentation :)

Comment: Yeah, slice it then as suggested in the posted answer. For horz flipping, use `a[:,::-1]` and use the same slicing, i.e. `a[:,::-1][:,:12,:12,:]` and so on. For vert flipping : `a[:,:,::-1]`.

Comment: @Divakar Oh that's cool! So, we can achieve everything with just having one copy of original array.  Would you like to add it as an answer?

Comment: Would like you to add some sources (docs) and add that as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [**slicing**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for this: we can specify a range for the second and third dimension like:

```
sub_img = img_arr[:, :12, :12 , :]
```

Then `sub_img.shape == (10000, 12, 12, 3)`. Here we thus specify a range of `0` to `12` (but we do not need to explicitly state `0`). We do this for the second and third dimension. It is also quite declarative: we construct a `sub_img` where the first index takes all (`:`), the second one up to the twelveth item (`:12`), etc.

Note that we do not need to specify tailing `:`s, we can also write:

```
sub_img = img_arr[:, :12, :12]  # no last ":"
```

## Slices as views

Note that we here **construct a view**, we do *not* copy the array, we only construct a view. So if we make changes in `img_arr` that are in the range of the view, we will be able to see that in `sub_img`, and vice versa. In case you need a copy, you can pass for instance the view through the `array` constructor:

```
sub_img = np.array(img_arr[:, :12, :12])  # making a copy, instead of a view
```

Using a view can be beneficial however since it uses almost no memory to store a view (here approximately 144 bytes, whereas a copy will require approximately 34 megabytes), and furthermore the construction of a view is almost instantly (usually it scales with the *number of dimensions*), whereas a copy will scale with the number of elements.

## Arbitrary number of dimensions using `slice` objects

In case the number of dimensions is arbitrary for instance, we can also pass a tuple of `slice` objects.

For instance the first expression is equivalent to:

```
# equivalent to the first code fragment
indices = (slice(None), slice(12), slice(12))
sub_img = img_arr[indices]
```

So in case the number of dimensions is arbitrary, we can first construct such tuple. A tuple that will slice all dimensions to 12 except the first and the last is for instance:

```
# generalized with arbitrary number of dimensions
indices = (slice(None), *(slice(12) for _ in range(img_arr.ndim - 2)))
sub_img = img_arr[indices]
```

Comment: Very nice! So, I just have to hard-code the dimensions and at which locations in `img_arr` I want to crop using the slice indexes.

Comment: @kmario23: you do *not* have to hardcode, you can also use identifiers like `a = 12`, and then `sub_img = img_arr[:, :a, :a]`. You do not even have to hardcode the number of dimensions, you can pass a tuple with slices.